# How do I stop Xcode from bringing up a second tab when I hit a breakpoint?

Tags: xcode, debugging

Often when I hit a breakpoint a second tab appears and focus moves to the line with a breakpoint in this tab.  I already have a single tab which I'm focusing on.  So the tab popping up is distracting and frustrating.  I've searched for how to stop this behavior and looked through preferences/behaviors.  In the `Run` section both `Starts` and `Pauses` have no checkmarks checked.  I don't see anything checked in any of the other sections that would indicate this tab behavior should happen.